# How to create a windows batch file that combines all *NAD.TXT recursively within each directory?

Tags: batch-file, copy, xcopy, robocopy

I have a group of directories, and within those directories a have some files that end in *NAD.TXT. I need to combine, or copy together, all *NAD.TXT files within each directory to a file called COMBINED_NAD.TXT in each of the directories. Basically, so it combines those files and creates it in the same directory, and then recurses to the next one. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Asking volunteers to write code for you, for free, does not go over well here.  Please *edit* your question to show us how you've tried to solve the problem yourself, with code.

Comment: I have tried... I can get it to work within one directory using: copy /a *NAD.TXT COMBINED_NAD.TXT... but can't get it to work recursing subdirectories individually. Below is what I tried: - for %f in (`dir /b /s *NAD.TXT`) do type “%f” >> COMBINED_NAD.TXT // AND // 
for /F “usebackq delims==” %f in (`dir /b /s *NAD.TXT`) do type “%f” >> COMBINED_NAD.TXT - neither worked as I need

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Please, edit your question to add the information you have written in the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
for /d /r %%a in (*) do (
    del "%%~fa\COMBINED_NAD.TXT" >nul 2>nul 
    copy /b "%%~fa\*NAD.TXT" "%%~fa\COMBINED_NAD.TMP"
    ren "%%~fa\COMBINED_NAD.TMP" "COMBINED_NAD.TXT"
)
```

For each directory, recursively :

- If the target file exists, remove it
- Combine all the source files into target. `.tmp` extension ensures the target file will not be processed as a source file
- Rename the target file to final name

Comment: That works perfectly. Thank you. IS there any way to add the directory name to the start of the file it creates - for example - "1_COMBINED_NAD.TXT" where the directory the files are created within is "1"?

Comment: @USLG, as `%%a` is holding a reference to the folder being processed, `%%~nxa` will return the name (with extension if present) of the folder. Change the file deletion and rename lines: `del "%%~fa\%%~nxa_COMBINED_NAD.TXT"`, `ren "%%~fa\COMBINED_NAD.TMP" "%%~nxa_COMBINED_NAD.TXT"`